# Any ideas how to fix java.lang.outofmemoryerror android listview error?

Tags: java, android, listview

all Im getting the error `java.lang.outofmemoryerror BitmapFactory` error and I need some help on fixing it and this is the best option I have, i know that you can scale the images to stop them from  using too much memory but not quite sure how to go about it with the code I have.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
  String[] web = {
          //77 Images
  } ;
  Integer[] imageId = {
          //77 Images
  };
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PositionList adapter = new
            PositionList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                if(position == 0) {
                    //code specific to first list item    
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Position0.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

        -------------------Repeats--------------------------

               if(position == 77) {
                    //code specific to first list item    
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Position77.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
```

I tried using the examples from here but no luck implementing them - [ImageAdapter and ListView (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049821/imageadapter-and-listview-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-bu)

Comment: bitmap is too big, recreating many of them its pretty much bigger biggest.. resize/crop your images..

Comment: Wouldn't that mean keeping a thumbnail image and a high res image ?

Comment: Use picasso library, its free and it's easy to use

Comment: no it means get ur image from its source and resize it before you bring it to the listview to use it..triming ur images to android reasonable size helps keep ur app responsive.. **400 *400**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had a a same problem. You can use picasso or Universal Image Loader.
I suggest to Universal Image Loader. Picasso has some problems.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader